# Unwind two segues

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

Definition of (the relevant part in) my app:

I have map in my view (MAP). User clicks a view, app reverse geocodes to get the address and segues to another view (PICKER), it lets user select from picker the name she wants for the place or go to another view and give custom name (CUSTOM).

[image: Storyboard of the app]

Problem is that when I try to unwind from CUSTOM it fails.

In custom I unwind to the same method as from PICKER that I have in MAP's controller i.e.

```
@IBAction func unwindCancel(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // do nothing as saving was cancelled
    return
}

@IBAction func unwindSave(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.reloadGeodesics()
}
```

Below I present how I made in the storyboard the unwinding, i.e. ctrl drag Cancel (and Save) to exit and select corresponding Action segue.

[image: This is my action segue]

These are my error messages

> 2015-11-02 14:58:59.753 via[19620:2883125]
>   -[via.LocationNamePickerViewController unwindSave:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bb35770
>
> 2015-11-02 14:58:59.789 via[19620:2883125] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[via.LocationNamePickerViewController unwindSave:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7bb35770'

when I click save. `via` is my app name and `LocationNamePickerViewController` is the controller of PICKER.
I have looked many tutorials and to me I seem to be doing everything right.

Is this a problem of doing the segue from clicking Other in PICKER to CUSTOM wrongly? Does the navigation controller between the MAP and PICKER crash the compiler? From the error it looks like PICKER's controller cannot delegate the action segue call to the MAP's controller. Can this happen and if it happens how can it be fixed? Everything works fine in the PICKER, the problem is just with unwinding the CUSTOM.

Answer (score 2):

The way you create unwind segue is not right,you should create segue like this

**Control + drag from Location Enter VC to Map Exit**

Gif

[image]

Comment: I did it this way (after removing the unnecessary Navigation controller between), but still the same error message

Comment: You do not need to delete any NavigationController,just drag the bar button to Map VC exit,I post a gif

Comment: Didn't work, couldn't upload my .gif here so [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixq0lbvt0fjzovh/animation.gif?dl=0) is what I did. Same error message, I don't get it, now everything should be very trivial (being fighting with this problem a week now)

Comment: I think, I must be loosing the stack of views, otherwise it shouldn't crash, do I have a wrong segue type from PICKER to CUSTOM? I use Show (e.g. Push), i.e. the same from MAP to PICKER. Of course, this sounds weird, could it by xcode bug even?

Comment: I create the same segue stack just as the screenshot you post.I used the way I post to create unwind segue,and it works.

Comment: Then I need to have something in-between which crashes it. IMHO it should work like you say. Gotta rebuild that (again), thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

You placed UINavigationController after Map View, so LocationNamePicker controller and Location Name Enter controller is on stack of that navigation controller, so it seems it doesn't recognize Map View Controller's unwind action even you selected that action in storyboard.

Why don't you put navigation controller before Map View Controller?

I think it will not crash then.